# How to return ordered objects from django CBV(ListView) when you click a button or link in the template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, sql-order-by

So I'm building an e-commerce store with Django(First project after learning). I need to click on Sort in the template, and have the CBV return an object that's ordered by either, price, or whatever field I specify in the request. This is what I have so far

**Template**
Sort by Lowest Price

**View**

```
class ClotheListView(ListView):
model = Clothe
paginate_by = 8

def get_filter_param(self):
    # Grab the absolute url and then retrieve the filter param
    filter_param = self.request.path.split("/")[-1]
    return filter_param

def get_queryset(self):
    filter_param = self.get_filter_param()
    if(filter_param != ""):
        queryset = self.model.objects.filter(cloth_gender=filter_param)
    else:
        queryset = self.model.objects.all()
    return queryset

    return clothes_filtered_list.qs

def get_ordering(self):
    ordering = self.request.GET.get('ordering', '-cloth_price')
    return ordering

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context
```

**Url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.ClotheListView.as_view(), name="clothe_list"),
path('<slug:slug>', views.ClotheListView.as_view(),
     name="clothe_list_category"),
path('<int:pk>/', views.ClotheDetailView.as_view(), name="clothe_detail")
```

]

Comment: can you add template.html you use?

Comment: yes, let me do that

Comment: hi, I was unable to add the .html, I've tried several times without getting it

Answer (score 0):

ok, so this is how I did it:

**Template**

```html
<span class="float-end d-none d-lg-block mt-3">
          Sort by: Price -
          <a href="{{request.path}}?ordering=-cloth_price">High To Low</a> |
          Price:
          <a href="{{request.path}}?ordering=+cloth_price">Low to High</a>
        </span>
```

**View**

```
class ClotheListView(ListView):

model = Clothe
paginate_by = 8

def get_filter_param(self):
    # Grab the absolute url and then retrieve the filter param
    filter_param = self.request.path.split("/")[-1]
    return filter_param

def get_queryset(self):
    # code for price sorting
    default_order = "cloth_name"
    order_param = ""
    user_filter = ""
    try:
        order_param = self.request.GET.get('ordering').strip()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        user_filter = self.request.GET.get('filter').strip()
    except:
        pass

    order_by = order_param or default_order
    # End of sorting code

    filter_param = self.get_filter_param()
    if(filter_param != "" or not filter_param):
        if(user_filter != ""):
            queryset = self.model.objects.filter(
                cloth_gender=filter_param, cloth_category=user_filter)
        else:
            queryset = self.model.objects.filter(
                cloth_gender=filter_param)
    else:
        queryset = self.model.objects.all()
    return queryset.order_by(order_by)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.ClotheListView.as_view(), name="clothe_list"),
path('<slug:slug>', views.ClotheListView.as_view(),
     name="clothe_list_category"),
path('<int:pk>/', views.ClotheDetailView.as_view(), name="clothe_detail")
]
```